# Accessing Sharepoint 2013 list from a plain old HTML page (not on SharePoint server)

Tags: rest, jquery, html

I have a STRONG need for this. I created dynamic HTML pages that use AJAX to bring in XML files from an Excel spreadsheet.

I REALLY want to store the list information in SharePoint 2013 and access that list from my HTML pages.

So, I want my HTML page to make a call to the SharePoint 2013 list.

Can I do this with REST? Thanks.

Comment: HTML or ASPX? Under IIS?

Comment: HTML only. We are under unix I believe where the html pages are.

Comment: And do you need only read or write to?

Comment: I just need to read from it and place the Title, etc into the page. Myself and the client can use the SharePoint list to upload the information inside SharePoint.

Comment: I think you can use REST

Comment: Can you please provide a description?

Comment: Try RSS solution. Is more standard and you can find components to parse RSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RSS feed` with selected columns from list & use that `RSS feed URL` in HTML page so you will get the result from the `RSS feed`. You just need to extract the RSS Feed details into HTML once.

You can get the list data in SharePoint using it but only for view purpose.

Follow steps below mentioned

> First of Publish your data for public view you need to enable
>   Anonymous access for this announcement and news lists.
>
> Now Go to List -> List setting -> RSS Setting -> checked required
>   columns -> click OK
>
> Now open List RSS Feed Link form List Ribbon. using this
>   link you can get data in to your HTML site.
>
> In HTML site you can use third party RSS viewer control.

Comment: I'll give this a shot. I do only want to view the list into the page. If I get the RSS feed, can I just parse it myself? I want to load it into my page design.

Comment: You can find code to parse the code from RSS feed easily as it is available here...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10943544/how-to-parse-an-rss-feed-using-javascript

Comment: Alas, nothing works in the above stackoverflow.com to parse the RSS. I was able to get SharePoint to give me the RSS feed that I can hit via the URL in Internet Explorer, but I can't get it through the examples. It maybe because I'm accessing it from a different server?